# How to display sqlite string image in flutter . My Program has getting error "Invalid image data" error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm using SQLite for storing data locally. insert an image as a string and get them to show here is the error that occurs _Exception (Exception: Invalid image data).

Encode image code:

```
final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
if (image == null) return;
final imagePermanent = File(image.path);
setState(() => _image = imagePermanent);
imageData = base64Encode(_image!.readAsBytesSync());
print(imageData);
return imageData;}
```

Decode image in display page:

```
showImage(String image) {
    return Image.memory(base64Decode (image) );
}
```

Display in code:

```
showImage(widget.euser.image.toString()),
```

Error Shows :

```
Exception has occurred._Exception (Exception: **Invalid image data**)
```

Console logs show like this:

```
E/FlutterJNI(30407): Failed to decode image  
E/FlutterJNI(30407): android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException:  
  Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.
E/FlutterJNI(30407):    
  at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.nCreate(Native Method)
E/FlutterJNI(30407):    
  at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.access$200(ImageDecoder.java:173)
E/FlutterJNI(30407):    
  at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ByteBufferSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:250)
E/FlutterJNI(30407):    
  at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmapImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1862)
E/FlutterJNI(30407):    
  at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.java:1855)
E/FlutterJNI(30407):    
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.decodeImage(FlutterJNI.java:514)
```

Error image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RRzo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you not to save image using SQlite as it's not made for storing such a long string ( it's not as robust and has been designed for storing small values ) . Although if you want to store an image within you app , you can use the following code to store it in data directory of external storage

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.yourflutterapp/files/imagepermanat.png
```

you can use the following function :

```
Future<File?> captureAndSaveImage() async {
final pickedImage = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: 
ImageSource.camera);
if (pickedImage == null) return null;

try {
final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (directory != null) return 
File(pickedImage.path).copy('${directory.path}/name.png');
 } catch (e) {
return null;
 }
}
```

This function can be called as :

```
File? file = await captureAndSaveImage();
```

**You can still use SQlite for storing the path of the image you saved**

**Also , if its converted to a network image ,further in the code , just use a [cachedImageNetwork](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package**